# ansible cisco ios_command module "unable to set terminal parameters"

Tags: ansible

I am running ansible v 2.5 and trying to run a basic "show clock" command on my switch.

How ever it errors out saying that it is unable to set terminal parameters,

following is my yml File:

```
---
- hosts: ios_devices
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  vars_prompt:
  - name: "mgmt_username"
    prompt: "Username"
    private: no
  - name: "mgmt_password"
    prompt: "Password"

  tasks:

  - name: SYS | Define provider
    set_fact:
      provider:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ mgmt_username }}"
        password: "{{ mgmt_password }}"

  - name: IOS | Show clock
    ios_command:
      provider: "{{ provider }}"
      commands:
        - show clock
    register: clock

  - debug: msg="{{ clock.stdout }}"
```

and on running the playbook i receive the following error:

```
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: FAILED! => {"msg": "unable to set terminal parameters"}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error `unable to set terminal parameters` means that one (or both) of the following commands failed:

- `terminal length 0`
- `terminal width 512`

Try running those commands manually on your Cisco IOS switch to check they are supported.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem but solved it after using "asa_command" module:

```
- hosts: ASA
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    cli:
      host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
      username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
      authorize: yes
      auth_pass: "{{ ansible_password }}"


  tasks:
    - name: run multiple commands and evaluate the output
      asa_command:
         commands:
            - show service-policy
            - show running-config
         provider: "{{ cli }}"
      register: output

    - debug:
          msg: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, have to be able to set the following two command:

```
terminal length 0
```

and

```
terminal width 512
```

You don't need specific privileges to be able to issue these commands. Both can be issued from the Cisco's regular CLI exec mode.

Check your username "commands" authorization privileges, that could be the issue. You may have a limited command authorization configured on your IOS device. If you have access to "show running" command, try checking aaa authorization using the following:

```
show run | i aaa authorization commands
```

If you see it defined on your router/switch, you'll need to talk to your network admin and make sure they allow you or the ansible user you are using to be able to issue "terminal length" and "terminal width" commands. I am not aware of any other way around this.

Just FYI, the "terminal" command is only limited to the user current active session, and will NOT affect any router operational parameters in any way. Once you logout, the terminal parameters will reset to its default.

As for the asa_command workaround, that's not recommended really. asa and ios have different output formatting, so, although may work for some cases, it is guaranteed to fail in other cases.

If you are using an ASA with PIXOS and having the same problem, use the "Pager" command to set the length of your terminal.

Please check out the following Cisco Community link for more information on setting terminal length on different Cisco devices:

[Show the Complete Configuration without Breaks/Pauses on Cisco Router/Switches, ASA Firewall and WLC (Wireless LAN Controller)](https://community.cisco.com/t5/networking-documents/show-the-complete-configuration-without-breaks-pauses-on-cisco/ta-p/3115114)

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to get this issue as well but for IOS XR. the problem for me is that i have created a set of new and unique credentials just for Ansible to access my devices and did not set the proper privileges for these. In my specific case, configuring the new set of credentials to be part of the "sysadmin" group solved the problem for me:

```
Cisco-IOS-XR Device

username ansible
 secret ansible
 **group sysadmin**
```

In case of the IOS / IOS XE devices should check the aaa configuration for the proper privileges as well.

Last but not least, for ASA, i assume it would be the exact same.